# How do I vertically align elements within a div in CSS?

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have the following bit on my site...
[image: Current Results]

This is the HTML output for the previous bit:

```
<div class="featured" style="background: url(http://localhost/basecommand/attachments/8d7fd632111cf768ec62d5ad084d8059.jpg);">

                    <h1>This Is a Test Article</h1>

                    <div class="arrow left">

                        <i class="fi-arrow-left"></i>

                    </div>

                    <div class="arrow right">

                        <i class="fi-arrow-right"></i>

                    </div>

                    <div class="clear"></div>

                    <div class="info">

                        <p>https://www.bungie.net/pubassets/1319/Destiny_31.png

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, inani accusata et duo, ad sit veniam interpretaris. Sea scripta nostrum ex, liber fastidii ea duo. Id vim nobis option contentiones, mea probatus praesent ut. Sea ex ...</p>

                        <h2><a href="http://localhost/basecommand/index.php/articles/This-Is-a-Test-Article/1">Read More</a></h2>

                    </div>

                </div>
```

This is the CSS I have so far

```
.featured {
    width: 620px;
    height: 349px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0px;
}

.featured h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(183, 31, 47, 0.5);
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 15px 0px;
    width: 50%
}

.featured .arrow {
    font-size: 72px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.featured .info {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.featured p {
    padding: 10px;
}

.featured a {
    color: #fff;
}

.featured h2 {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

What modifications can I make to my css so that the description box("info" class) is aligned to the bottom of the parent div "featured" class?  I would also like the arrows to be aligned in the middle, if possible.  How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: think you missed to add the styles of `left` and `right` for the arrows...

Comment: What about using `absolute` positioning? `.info {bottom: 0; position: absolute; width: 100%;}`

Comment: @HashemQolami but never forget to add `position:relative` to the container, otherwise your box will appear at the bottom of the image, not the container

Comment: @webeno That's part of my assumptions.

Comment: @HashemQolami well, considering it's just a comment, think that's ok, it wouldn't be if you provided it as an answer ;)

Comment: @webeno I don't feel answering questions right now :) However I note that absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to their containing block. Using `relative` positioning on a box creates a new containing block for absolutely positioned elements *(but not fixed ones)* (anything other than `static` positioning will do the same thing) Otherwise they'll be positioned relative to the initial containing block.

Comment: Webeno : I had the left and right styles further up the style sheet as a "global" class... The image is actual browser rendering so that is working correctly ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the "featured" class on the bottom, you can use position.

```
.featured {
   position: relative;
}

.featured .info {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
}
```

As for aligning the arrows to the center. This works by positioning the arrow at the 50% mark, which is half. But we then move the div up by half of the height. I specified the height of 20px, and set the div to move up 10px with the negative margin-top.

```
.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

For more information about Vertical-Align, please look at these resources.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/

http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/

Comment: think the arrows' vertical positioning part is missing from your answer, though the OP didn't paste his style code for the `left` and `right` classes of those...

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sS7X6/)

Use position absolute as below for your .info class and use any position other then static in .*featured* class:

```
.featured .info {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);

    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;


}
```

Comment: this will get the `.info` box out of the container... you need to add `position:relative` to the container (in this case `.featured`).

Comment: And why only relative i can use any other then static