# Centering a div both horizontally and vertically at all times on a responsive parent

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I have a header that I would like to keep centered inside a parent image div both horizontally and vertically at all times **when the parent div does not have a fixed width and height but instead has a responsive width and height** using Twitter Bootstrap 3.1's responsive columns.

HTML:

```
<div id ="firstholder" class= " col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <a href="home.html" title="Home" class="imglink"> 
        <div class="item1"><h1 class="slickfont1" >Home</h1>
        </div><img src="/images/slide2.JPG" alt="City Lights Image"  class="img-responsive" >
    </a>
</div>


#firstholder {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
}


a.imglink  {
    background:  #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
}

.item1 {
    height:150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.slickfont1 {
    z-index:10;
    color: #fff;
    position:absolute;
    font-family: 'Bowlby One SC', cursive;
    font-size: 37px;
    font-weight:lighter;  
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow:0 0 0 transparent, -2px 2px 2px  #1542bd;
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle

Comment: hi @SULTAN here is a link to the fiddle I made http://jsfiddle.net/W2DfT/ I just cannot figure out how to get images on there...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575851/how-do-i-vertically-align-elements-within-a-div-in-css/22575885#22575885 duplicate, or atleast very similar.

Comment: @David Im trying to make sure the div is always centered both horizontally and vertically....not sure that is a duplicate

Comment: What div (ID) do you want always centered? I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly what you want centered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to center a <div> on a page vertically and horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

Comment: @David I am trying to center div.item1

Comment: Watch this codepen (the absolute centering) http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/gEiDt

Answer (score 3):

You can use this nice method by Chris Coyier at CSS Tricks, he uses percentages and CSS3's transform:translate to achieve what you need. [**Centering Percentage Width/Height Elements**](http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/)

Now as you're using Bootstrap, so you're to tweak it for yourself.

The code from Chris Coyier:

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;

  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

Better to go to CSSTricks (using above link) and study the whole Post (you'll also find the reason of using it and why its better than other methods of centring).
I hope this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood you right,  but let's start from here:

CSS:

```
div.center {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

div.inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="title">
            Title Here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this what you are trying to do?  assuming the gray background is an image? **[SAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/fYcE2/)**

Comment: YES that is exactly what I am trying to do but my div.center (#firstholder) has a variable width and height, not fixed.

Comment: From my above HTML, the width is col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 (twitter bootstraps responsive columns) and the height varies based on what screen width you are in

Comment: @whatIsperfect Okay, good then.  Just make `width:auto; height:auto;` in the `div.center`     -     and, add padding to `div.inner`       - here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fYcE2/1/

Comment: @whatIsperfect P.S. Also, you can of-course remove the `width` and `height` from the `.div.center`

Comment: thanks so much for the help...when I put width:auto, my picture size distorts because I already specify the width using Twitter Bootstrap's predefined column width. Then I tried not specifying the width or height on div.center and still no luck :(

Comment: I'm using a workaround for now by just assigning margin-left:38%; & margin-top:25%; to the inner div. Have a look for yourself at the three centered images: www.getcitylights.com